# Why these pixel-equivalent elements have different real size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m trying to code blog and i want to synchronise positions of timeline events and it´s posts. I coded it as two different columns and I´m trying to get height of post with jQuery and then count the size of blank space in timeline event. Everything seems to be set OK, console gives me equivalent numbers and so the programmer tools in chrome. You can see the height of the post [here](https://pasteboard.co/GS0xtN9.png) and these are heights of elements next to it: [element1](https://pasteboard.co/GS0y2gJ.png), [element2](https://pasteboard.co/GS0yA5l.png), [element3](https://pasteboard.co/GS0yXaZ.png). Together, it 740px but the main element-post is also 740px.

So, I would like to know, how is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: that picture is worthless! anyway ... when calculating the height of an element, are you talking about content box height, padding box height, are there any top/bottom margins for any of the content?

Comment: Sorry for the pictures. Anyway, thank you for your comment. I figured it out! I had to subtract the margin of element on timeline. Thank you! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the pictures, the margin is not included in the size. So, for instance, while that "G+" icon may be 32x32, with margins, it taking up what looks to be closer to maybe 48x48. And the height of the article is only referring to up to the green line (the padding).

There are probably multiple ways of solving this, but using what you're doing now, if you wrap those margin-spaced elements in divs, then those wrapping divs will have the correct sizing themselves.